# Is there any way to trigger functions of Google Sheet 1 from Google Sheet 2?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any way I can trigger functions of Google Sheet 1 script editor from Google sheet 2?

I read the documentation of google sheet scripts and found out about libraries but having trouble understanding how it works:
1) In properties of project by the project key, it says "Depreciated" - does that means i cannot share libraries anymore?

2) In google sheet 2, when i am trying to add library by entering project key of Google sheet 1, i keep getting following error:

**The selected library must have a saved version in order to be included in another script. Open the project you wish to add as a library, save a version and try again.**

Comment: `Warning: A script that uses a library does not run as quickly as it would if all the code were contained within a single script project. Although libraries can make development and maintenance more convenient, you should use them sparingly in projects where speed is critical. Because of this issue, library use should be limited in add-ons.` So pretty much, use libraries if what you are trying to do you want to be slow and clunky.

Comment: Hi @CodeCamper I am ok with slow process as long as I am able to trigger something in another sheet. Any idea how I can resolve the above error?

Comment: Did lamblichus' answer work for you?

Comment: If your objective is to **reuse** code without copying and pasting the entire code to another Apps Script project bound to another spreadsheet, then using a library is the only option other than an add-on.  If you want to trigger a totally different function in another spreadsheet, that's different.  It's possible, in an indirect way, but I'm not sure if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully add a library of script #1 to script #2, follow these steps:

(1) Create a library of script #1 in `File > Manage Versions...` and `Save New Version`, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version).

(2) Copy the `Script ID` of script #1 in `File > Project properties...` (**not `Project key`**).

(3) Use library created in step 1: in script #2, go to `Resources > Libraries...` and add the `Script ID` you retrieved in step 2, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#using_a_library).

#### Update:

Once you have added the library to script #2, you can access its functions by writing the word you added to field `Identifier` in step 3. For example, if the library identifier is set to `YourLibrary` and one of the functions in the library is called `yourFunction`, you can run that function in your second script by writing `YourLibrary.yourFunction()`.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you @lamblichus for the steps - very helpful. I just did everything as per the steps mentioned above. One last thing I am missing. how can i trigger function of sheet1 from sheet2?

Comment: You're welcome @kuml. Can you explain what you mean by `trigger function of sheet1 from sheet2`?

Comment: @kuml I updated my answer based on your comment. I'm not sure that's what you meant. Let me know if that's the case.