# Share a custom google sheet function with another email address without showing the source code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Iv'e written a custom google sheet function using Google Apps Script, and i would like to share it with another spreadsheet user, but i do not want to share the functions source code.

I've converted the Google Apps Script to a project, but now i have no idea how to link the project back to my sheet, so the function will work again.

I also do not want to publish the AddIn to the marketplace.

Test As Addin also doesn't work, the sheet is opened in a new tab, but the cells with the custom function says `#NAME?`.

What am i missing?

Comment: It says  #NAME?  because the custom function is not part of the active spreadsheet. Like you said, it is saved on a different project. The error says that a function with this name does not exist. I believe what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: So the goal, sharing a custom function to other others, but not the source code is not possible? in that way or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation / issues:**

- The error `#NAME?` indicates that you are trying to use a function
  that does not exist. As you also mentioned, this function does not
  belong to the active spreadsheet but on a different project.
- Unfortunately, it is not possible to share a custom function with other spreadsheets directly.

**Possible Workarounds:**

- You can create an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview).
- Another workaround solution would be to create a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). That is a great alternative and the documentation is quite straightforward.

---

**Related:**

- [Creating add ons in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59661799/11225291)
- [How to call library function as custom function from spreadsheet formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616415/how-to-call-library-function-as-custom-function-from-spreadsheet-formula)