# Use a script from google app script in all my documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I made this function in google app script that makes some changes in a google doc:

```js
function boldKeywords() {
  // Words that will be put in bold:
  var keywords = ["end", "proc", "fun"];

  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();

  var Style = {};
  Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  for (j in keywords) {

    var found = body.findText(keywords[j]);

    while(found != null) {
      var foundText = found.getElement().asText();
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      foundText.setAttributes(start, end, Style)
      found = body.findText(keywords[j], found);
    }
  }

}
```

And I would like to be able to use it in all my documents, but for now, I am only able to use it in the doc form which I open google app script, somebody knows how could I be able to use it in all my documents, preferably from the add-ons menu?

Comment: I have a bunch of scripted tools that I use when I write stories.  I make a copy.  Open the script editor to authorize the script.  Create an installable trigger and then close it. Open it and began writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to create add-ons in Apps Script, you might want to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661799/creating-add-ons-in-google-apps-script)

> **In order to use the add-on in other files, you would have to do one of the following:**
>
> (1) Publish the add-on, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons#publishing_instructions).
>
> (2) Test the add-on via `Run > Test as add-on...`. I wouldn't recommend this, since you would have to add each file you want to use the add-on with first, and open the file from there.

It was mentioned that to use the add-on to different files, you need to publish your add-on which needs to pass the [add-on publication requirements](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#review_the_add-on_publication_requirements)

---

One workaround I could suggest is to copy your apps script code to specific document file programmatically using [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts). You can choose your preferred programming language to use this API, one example would be [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python)

### What you need to do?

1. create an apps script project using [projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create). You just need to provide the script `title` and the `parentId` in the request body

> **Note:**
>
> **parentId** : The Drive ID of a parent file that the created script project is bound to. This is usually the ID of a Google Doc, Google Sheet, Google Form, or Google Slides file. If not set, a standalone script project is created.

Sample Request Body:

```
{
  "title": "InboundScript",
  "parentId": "1_XlY8tgcJgj13FItftGrF77i7zMYyf-Rxxxxx"
}
```

- where `1_XlY8tgcJgj13FItftGrF77i7zMYyf-Rxxxxx` is the file id of the Google Docs file where I want to create a script

2. Include your script in your project using [projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)

Sample Request Body:

**Note:** You can replace the timezone in appsscript.json file

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "appsscript",
      "type": "JSON",
      "source": "{\n  \"timeZone\": \"Asia/Manila\",\n  \"dependencies\": {\n  },\n  \"exceptionLogging\": \"STACKDRIVER\",\n  \"runtimeVersion\": \"V8\",\n  \"oauthScopes\": [\n    \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly\"\n  ]\n}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Code",
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": "function onOpen(e) {\n  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.\n  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.\n      .createMenu('Custom Menu')\n      .addItem('Bold Keywords', 'boldKeywords')\n      .addToUi();\n}\n\nfunction boldKeywords() {\n  // Words that will be put in bold:\n  var keywords = [\"end\", \"proc\", \"fun\"];\n\n  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();\n  var body = document.getBody();\n\n  var Style = {};\n  Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;\n\n  for (j in keywords) {\n\n    var found = body.findText(keywords[j]);\n\n    while(found != null) {\n      var foundText = found.getElement().asText();\n      var start = found.getStartOffset();\n      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();\n      foundText.setAttributes(start, end, Style)\n      found = body.findText(keywords[j], found);\n    }\n  }\n\n}",
      "functionSet": {
        "values": [
          {
            "name": "onOpen"
          },
          {
            "name": "boldKeywords"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Output:

[image]

- A custom menu was added in the Google Doc file

If you open the script editor:

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Bold Keywords', 'boldKeywords')
      .addToUi();
}

function boldKeywords() {
  // Words that will be put in bold:
  var keywords = ["end", "proc", "fun"];

  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();

  var Style = {};
  Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  for (j in keywords) {

    var found = body.findText(keywords[j]);

    while(found != null) {
      var foundText = found.getElement().asText();
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      foundText.setAttributes(start, end, Style)
      found = body.findText(keywords[j], found);
    }
  }

}
```

**appsscript.json**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Manila",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Okey, thank you very much